# System not adding AM to end of .net ToLongTimeString()

Tags: c#, windows

I know I can do better with the coding but want to avoid a code deployment. Why would the AM stop being appended? The PM is appended. The code creates a file name using this as part of the string value. System.DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString()

Comment: Please post your code, preferably a small program that will compile and run that shows the problem you're seeing.

Comment: What is your current culture? As it says on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tolongtimestring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) the result is culture dependant.

Comment: This shows `5:12:00 AM` as expected: `System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US");
Console.Write(System.DateTime.Now.AddHours(-12).ToLongTimeString());`

Comment: Current culture on the server is en US

Answer (score 3):

As it says on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tolongtimestring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) the result is culture dependant. For example, the culture `en-GB` doesn't print it but `en-US` does.

You could always write your own format string based on the example they give rather than relying on the user's culture:

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("h:mm:ss tt");
```

Comment: string fileName = "tranDetails" + System.DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString() + ".csv";

Comment: The PM is added afternoon. It just started happening 3 days ago. The server folks have not patched the server or rebooted it. The network switch the server is on stopped responding around that time and was repaired.